# Php string replace issue

Tags: php

I've some text:

> Reply: Alter pot water it your pot. Please Reply this text. If you Reply this text you get some money. Please Reply

So i want to replace first `Reply` text with `Hi`. Not another `Reply` text.

I know i can do this with `str_replace()` function with php. But it replace all `Reply` text with `Hi`. But i need to replace first `Reply` text.

how do i do this with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4<sup>th</sup> parameter of [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is the max replacement to be done. Set it to 1.

```
$str = preg_replace('/reply/i', 'Hi', $str, 1);
```